# How do I add X-RequestId header to a named HttpClient created by DI injected HttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

When a request is made to my ASP.NET Core Web API, it must contain a `X-RequestId` header.  I want to add this same `X-RequestId` header to downstream API calls.  These API calls are made using named `HttpClients`.  These clients are instantiated by `HttpClientFactory`.  `HttpClientFactory` is injected into services classes.

I tried setting the `X-RequestId` header in the `configureClient` Action delegate, but this only gets called once at run-time. I need the header to be set for each request coming in to my web API.

**Not Called Each Request**

```
services.AddHttpClient(PatClientName, (sp, c) =>
{
    // TODO: this only gets called once, so setting the RequestId header here won't work
    var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PatServiceOptions>>().Value;

    var httpContextAccessor = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    var requestIdHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderName.RequestId].FirstOrDefault();
    if (requestIdHeader != null)
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderName.RequestId, requestIdHeader);

    var baseAddress = options.BaseAddress;
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
});
```

**Different Approach?**

Would a better approach to be to create a scoped or transient object that contains the request ID, and inject that into all of my services that need it?

Comment: Create a base class for controllers, like BaseController and inside base constructor use IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor to do your things.

Comment: When you do the request just add the header in the call? Or do you have problems getting at the X-RequestId value there? For example because you are in a singleton service independent from the controller?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do open telemetry style requests?  I'd avoid doing this manually, and look at the OpenTelemetry nuget packages that handle all of this in the 'standard' way.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  It turns out that my original approach was working - I just misinterpreted what I was seeing. That said, I like @dropoutcoder's answer and approach much better than mine, so I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom handler...

```cs
public class RequestIdHeaderMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _sp;

    public RequestIdHeaderMessageHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _sp = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = _sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var requestIdHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers[HeaderName.RequestId].FirstOrDefault();
        if (requestIdHeader != null)
            request.Headers.Add(HeaderName.RequestId, requestIdHeader);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

...and inserted it into a handler chain by configuring additional http message handlers if you want to use it only by specific client(s).

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(PatClientName, (sp, c) =>
{
    var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<PatServiceOptions>>().Value;

    var baseAddress = options.BaseAddress;
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
})
.ConfigureAdditionalHttpMessageHandlers((handlers, sp) => handlers.Insert(0, new RequestIdHeaderMessageHandler(sp));
```

In case, you would like to use it as a default for every client you can configure http client defaults instead.

```cs
services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(b =>
    b.ConfigureAdditionalHttpMessageHandlers((handlers, sp) => handlers.Insert(0, new RequestIdHeaderMessageHandler(sp))));
```

**Related info**

[HttpClient Message Handlers in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers#custom-message-handlers)

[.NET 8 Networking Improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-8-networking-improvements/?hmsr=joyk.com&utm_source=joyk.com&utm_medium=referral)

Comment: This is great.  It turns out that my original approach was working - I just misinterpreted what I was seeing.  That said, I like this approach much better.  Accepted answer.  Thank you.

Comment: One small change... In `RequestIdHeaderMessageHandler`, I believe `ServiceProvider` needs to be `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: Another small change I made.  In the last example - of adding the request ID message handler to all http clients - I removed the call to `ConfigureHttpClient()` because I don't want all of my other `HttpClients` to get the PAT service's base address. ;)

Comment: I am happy it guided you to find better solution. Thanks for an update to the answer. Happy coding.